# Selector CSS para número ordinal de posición

Tags: css, selectores

Seleccionar elementos con CSS en un rango determinado, es decir:

Tengo una tabla con sus respectivos `<tr>` ahora necesito que los `tr` que estén desde la cuarta posición hasta la novena (9) estén en color rojo

¿Como lo hago?

Comment: podrias asignarle un id a los <tr> que quieres, luego les das estilos dentro del .css

Comment: Estoy intentando jugar con :lt() y :gt() de CSS ya casi consigo la solución, pero gracias por tu aporte... quizá alguien responda algun code de ejemplo.

Comment: Prueba a usar :nth-child(). Si las posiciones de los tr son siempre las mismas te podría valer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>gt demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i < 11; $i++) { 
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;INICIO - '.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;INICIO - '.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;INICIO - '.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;FIN - '.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;FIN - '.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;FIN - '.$i.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';
    }
?>
</table>

<script>
limit = 10;
page = 11;

element = 'tr';
page = page<2?1:page;
from = (page>1)?(((page*limit)-limit)-1):false;
gt = (page>1)?':gt('+from+')':'';
selector = gt+':lt('+limit+')';
list = $(element+selector);
$(element).not(selector).css( "display", "none" );
console.log((list.length>0)?'Se estan mostrando los resultados de la pagina '+page:'No hay resultados de esta pagina.')
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
table tr:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+9) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
    <td>Prueba</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Mediante **CSS**, usando `nth-child(n)`, puedes elegir a que hijos quieres que les afecte un conjunto de reglas **CSS**, seleccionados por su posición dentro del DOM.

Comment: Esta bueno, pero para hacerlo mas dinámico hice esto, creí que no podría pero un lapiz y papel resuelve mucho...

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar esto:

```css
/* evitamos que el primer elemento cambie de color */   
  tr:nth-child(1) {
      background: white;
  }
  /* coloreamos elementos de 1 en 1 desde el 4 elemento */ 
  tr:nth-child(1n+4) {
      background: red;
  }
  /* y sobre escribimos la regla a partir del 9 */
  tr:nth-child(1n+9) {
      background: white;
  }
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Debo aprender como hacen esas inserciones en las respuestas, por ahora solo sé como insertar codigo con Ctrl+K jejejeje

Comment: @Arcaela Inserciones? te refieres al código ejecutable? es con Ctrl + m

Comment: No sabía cual era el Shortcut pero gracias :)